# how to insert a element at specific index in python list

Tags: python

I am creating a list whose items are to be mapped by index number. I tried using the `list.insert()` method. But still it always **adds the first element to 0th index** and I want the first element at 1st index. For example:

```
somelist=[]
somelist.insert(1,"Jack")
somelist.insert(2,"Nick")
somelist.insert(3,"Daniel")

>>print(somelist[1])
Nick # not Jack
```

how can I do this in Python? where I can insert element only at given index and let the list start from index 1.

Comment: `list.inset()` is *not* a "inser at an index" instead it is "insert before(or at) the index",  `somelist.insert(1,"Jack")` will insert at first at index `0` because no eleemnt exists before 1 index

Comment: Keep `somelist.insert(0,None)` 0 index as None

Comment: @AnupYadav This works thanks!

Comment: @AnupYadav Indeed a *not* good advice

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I tried like this: `somelist=[None]` for intialization, its not correct?

Comment: Why would you not just index the list with `n - 1` if your `n` is one based? Why are you really trying to shift the list elements?

Comment: instead of adding `None` at 0th index, better to change `print(somelist[1])` to `print(somelist[0])`

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes this is also the option but it would increase unnecessary complexity during using the list, so to avoid it I thought of creating the list with index starting from 1.

Comment: @MrAlpha, List is not an array. In arrays, you can add values at the index of your choice provided the index doesn't exceed the array size. But, in list the elements are appended one after another. List is typically dynamically created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you insert something into a empty list, it will always be starting from the first position. Do something like this as workaround:

```
somelist=[]
somelist.insert(0,"dummy")
somelist.insert(1,"Jack")
somelist.insert(2,"Nick")
somelist.insert(3,"Daniel")

#print(somelist[1])
print(somelist[1])
```

output:

```
Jack
```

Answer (score 2):

I think a dictionary could be helpful here if that will do.

Like

```
d={}
```

and insertion at required places is as easy as

```
d[1]="Jack"
d[2]="Nick"
d[3]="Daniel"
```

Now

```
print( d[1] )
```

will print

```
Jack
```

This way you won't have to use dummy values.

Comment: This is much better than using dummy elements, which make a list much less iterable.

Answer (score 1):

Your somelist array is empty, which means you can't add an item to the index 1 if there is no item in index 0..

With this i mean when you first try to insert "Jack" to index 1, it goes automatically to index 0, and then you insert "Nick" to index 2, and that goes to index 1... and last you print index 1 which is "Nick"

Comment: so should I initialize it with some item?

Comment: Remember that the first item in an array is index 0

Comment: @MrAlpha Depends, You must first learn what the `insert()` method do